# preventDefault on mouse up

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, fabricjs, preventdefault

this code doesn't work. How can I prevent context menu in fabrics?

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
    if(options.target){
        switch(options.e.button){
            case 0:
                // left click
                break;
            case 2:
                // right click
                options.e.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
$('canvas').contextmenu( function() {
    return false;
});
```

outside of `canvas.on('mouse:up'` ...

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43fmuwkx/)